# Python read and search String in a file

Tags: regex, python-3.4

I want to write a script to read apache.conf file and get "MaxClients" value, "Keepalive" value,"KeepAliveTimeout" value and "ServerLimit" value etc, to different arguments. But it should not be read if the line start with "#" value. I have written sample code as below, but it is not ignoring # value, Could someone help me to do this, I just need only the value.

```html
import re

#afile = open('apache.txt','r')
#for aline in afile:
#    aline1 = aline.rstrip()
#    ax = re.findall('MaxClients ',aline1 )
#    print(ax)

with open('apache.txt','r') as afile:
    for line in afile:
        match = re.search('MaxClients ([^,]+)', line )
        if match:
            print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `re.search` function like below.

```
match = re.search(r'^(?! *#).*MaxClients ([^,]+)', line )
```

`(?! *#)` negative lookahead which asserts that the start of the line  is not followed by a `#` symbol.

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)